# How to use range post_filter in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I cannot find examples of the syntax anywhere and the following does not work:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            { "term": { "category": "catname"   }}
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "post_filter": {
    "terms": {"type": ["foo1", "foo2"] },
    "range": { "price": { "gte": 300, "lte": 600 } }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to wrap all your `terms` filters in an additional `bool/must` filter:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "category": "catname"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "post_filter": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "terms": {  "type": [ "foo1", "foo2" ] }
        },
        {
          "range": {  "price": { "gte": 300, "lte": 600  } }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```